# Blazor TelerikTextBox get value based on custom/Regex validation

Tags: c#, forms, blazor, telerik, .net-6.0

I have a button which is disabled until all text inputs are not null or empty. However, besides checking for null or empty I need to validate the based on a custom validator or regular expressions.

The structure of my components is:
`AllForms.razor` contains `<InfoForm.razor />` and `<TelerikButton />`

For now, I change a boolean if the text input is not null or empty. Can I also check if the filled-in value meets the requirements of the customvalidator/regex?

InfoModel.cs
[image: Model.cs]

InfoForm.razor

```
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(_psfValidator.Email)">
                    <Template>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label for="email"><b>E-mail<span>*</span></b></label>
                            <TelerikTextBox PlaceHolder="E-mailadres" Value="@_psfValidator.Email" ValueChanged="@( (string s) => EmailOnChangeHandler(s) )" ValueExpression="@( () => _psfValidator.Email )"></TelerikTextBox>
                            <TelerikValidationMessage For="@(() => _psfValidator.Email)"></TelerikValidationMessage>
                        </div>
                    </Template>
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(_psfValidator.PhoneNumber)">
                    <Template>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label for="email"><b>Telefoon</b></label>
                            <TelerikTextBox PlaceHolder="Telefoonnummer" Value="@_psfValidator.PhoneNumber" ValueChanged="@( (string s) => PhonenumberOnChangeHandler(s) )" ValueExpression="@( () => _psfValidator.PhoneNumber )"></TelerikTextBox>
                            <TelerikValidationMessage For="@(() => _psfValidator.PhoneNumber)"></TelerikValidationMessage>
                        </div>
                    </Template>
                </FormItem>
```

AllForms.razor

```
<InfoForm.razor />

<TelerikButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" ThemeColor="primary" OnClick="@(() => { Value += 1; NextHandler(); })">Verder</TelerikButton>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. I put a Regex check inside the method that is called on `ValueChanged`.

If true the bool will be set to true, if not the bool will stay false and the button will stay disabled untill it matches the `Required` and `Regex`.